# How to copy files within a remote server?

Tags: scp, remote, file-copy

I would like to copy files in an remote server from one directory (in the remote server) to another (also in the same remote server). I tried this:

```
scp -r myacc@remote.server:/folder_a/*myfiles* ../folder_b
```

This did no give any error message, but it did not work. I also tried this:

```
scp -r myacc@remote.server:/folder_a/*myfiles* myacc@remote.server:/folder_b
```

which gave an error message:

> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> Received disconnect from : 2: Too many
>   authentication failures for myacc lost connection

How to copy files within a same server from one directory to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `ssh` and do:

```
ssh myacc@remove.server "cp /folder_a/*myfiles* /folder_b"
```